# Run Background process independent of the main execution flow

Tags: java, multithreading, background-process

I have a rest API that will upload a file to AWS and return a success response to the user.
I now have a requirement where I should post the uploaded data's details to another service for reporting purposes.
But the problem here is, this posting of data should be done independently without altering the response time of the API.

i.e. After uploading has been completed, I should run a background process that will post the data to another service, meanwhile the success response should be sent back to the user without any delay.

I have gone through some solutions and I tried something like with below snippet:

```
if(uploadSuccess) { 
  response.setStatus(HttpsServletResponse.SC_OK);
  //Post data to reporter
  CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> postUploadedData(fileName, 
  fileId));
}
```

With this approach the task is running in the background but the API response is held till the data post call has been completed.

Is there any other ways that I can achieve this?

Comment: why do you think  API response is held? It should not.

Comment: The problem is not in the code presented. CompletableFuture does run the task asynchronously, so something else must block further execution.